# No kinect2 devices found!

Tags: ros, iai-kinect2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am unable to open kinect2, neither with `rosrun kinect2_bridge kinect2_bridge`  nor with `roslaunch kinect2_bridge.launch`, the output is always the same:

`[Freenect2Impl] enumerating devices... [Freenect2Impl] 18 usb devices connected [Freenect2Impl] failed to open Kinect v2 @4:5! [Freenect2Impl] found 0 devices Error: no Kinect2 devices found!`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205849/no-kinect2-devices-found!/) by [manolovaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/21970/manolovaza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2015-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure you are using a usb3 port and you have modified udev/rules.d

---

Originally posted by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) with karma: 290 on 2015-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1